DropdownMenu does not pop down when filter an existing riverpod provider to create dropdownMenuEntries
I can run the below code perfectly fine.
But Problem 1: is that when the ref.watch(productsProvider(specificProductId: null, clientUid: widget.clientUid)) gets executed, if there was a ref.watch(prodictsProvider(specificProductId: null, clientUid: widget.null)) already watched by another widget on same app page, provider gets disposed-off. That widget (tried with both ConsumerWidget & ConsumerStatefulWidget) is still on screen though.
class ChooseProduct extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const ChooseProduct(
      {super.key, required this.productNameController, this.clientUid});

  final TextEditingController productNameController;
  final String? clientUid;

  @override
  ConsumerState<ChooseProduct> createState() => _ChooseProductState();
}

class _ChooseProductState extends ConsumerState<ChooseProduct> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AsyncValue<List<Product>> productsProvider = ref.watch(
        fetchProductsProvider(
            specificProductId: null, clientUid: widget.clientUid));
    return DropdownMenu(
      enabled: widget.clientUid == null ? false : true,
      controller: widget.productNameController,
      requestFocusOnTap: true,
      enableFilter: true,
      onSelected: (Object? pdt) {
        setState(() {
          if (pdt != null) widget.productNameController.text = pdt.toString();
        });
      },
      dropdownMenuEntries:
          productsProvider.map<List<DropdownMenuEntry<Object>>>(
        data: (AsyncData<List<Product>> products) {
          return products.value.map((pdt) {
            return DropdownMenuEntry(
              value: pdt.pid.toString(),
              label: pdt.pid,
            );
          }).toList();
        },
        error: (_) => [
          DropdownMenuEntry(
              label: 'Something unexpected happened. Try Again', value: '')
        ],
        loading: (_) {
          return [
            const DropdownMenuEntry(
                value: '', label: '', labelWidget: CircularProgressIndicator())
          ];
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Problem 2: To optimize cloud_firestore reads, when I modified the code as below to check if ref.exits(provider), and make my dropdownMenuEntries accordingly, DropdownMenu does not pop down and don't show/search any entries on typing. Console prints first 2 print commands in the code below but the 3rd print statement does not get executed where provider's value (which is a list) is mapped.
Could anyone please help to figure out what is done not correct here.
class ChooseProduct extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const ChooseProduct({super.key, required this.productNameController, this.clientUid});

  final TextEditingController productNameController;
  final String? clientUid;

  @override
  ConsumerState<ChooseProduct> createState() => _ChooseProductState();
}

class _ChooseProductState extends ConsumerState<ChooseProduct> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    //  CHANGE: CHECK IF REF EXISTS FOR COMPREHENSIVE PRODUCTS AND FILTER FOR SPECIFIC CLIENT, RATHER RE-FETCHING FOR A CLIENT AGAIN 
    
    final AsyncValue<List<Product>> productsProvider;
    List<DropdownMenuEntry<Object>> _ClientSpecificProducts = [];
    bool allPdtsFetched = false;
    if (ref.exists(fetchProductsProvider(specificProductId: null, clientUid: null))) {
      productsProvider = ref.watch(fetchProductsProvider(specificProductId: null, clientUid: null));
      allPdtsFetched = true;
    } else {
      productsProvider =
          ref.watch(fetchProductsProvider(specificProductId: null, clientUid: widget.clientUid));
    }

    return DropdownMenu(
      enabled: widget.clientUid == '' ? false : true,
      controller: widget.productNameController,
      requestFocusOnTap: true,
      enableFilter: true,
      expandedInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
      onSelected: (Object? pdt) {
        setState(() {
          if (pdt != null) widget.productNameController.text = pdt.toString();
        });
      },
      dropdownMenuEntries: productsProvider.map<List<DropdownMenuEntry<Object>>>(
        data: (AsyncData<List<Product>> products) {
          // PRINT STATEMENT 1
          print('\nAllPdtsFetched = ${allPdtsFetched}\nwidget.clientUid = ${widget.clientUid}\n');
          if (allPdtsFetched) {
            // PRINT STATEMENT 2
            print('CHECK');
            products.value.map((pdt) {
              // PRINT STATEMENT 3
              print('pdt.client_uid = ${pdt.client_uid}\nwidget.clientUid = ${widget.clientUid}\n');
              if (pdt.client_uid == widget.clientUid) {
                _ClientSpecificProducts.add(DropdownMenuEntry(
                  value: pdt.pid.toString(),
                  label: pdt.pid,
                ));
              }
            });
          }
          return allPdtsFetched == true
              ? _ClientSpecificProducts
              : products.value.map((pdt) {
                  return DropdownMenuEntry(
                    value: pdt.pid.toString(),
                    label: pdt.pid,
                  );
                }).toList();
        },
        error: (_) =>
            [DropdownMenuEntry(label: 'Something unexpected happened. Try Again', value: '')],
        loading: (_) {
          return [
            const DropdownMenuEntry(value: '', label: '', labelWidget: CircularProgressIndicator())
          ];
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


Anyone, please throw any idea. Could it be due to how I initialize productsProvider because it is conditional initialization?
